# What happens to an asynchronous WCF call when its client disposes or goes out of scope?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I am maintaining some code which has a class containing a method that calls a WCF method asynchronously using the Task pattern.

The code effectively looks like this:

```
public class Manager : IDisposable
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Task<bool> task;

        using (var client = new WcfClient())
        {
            task = client.ReallyDoSomethingAsync(123);
        }
    }
}
```

The manager itself is used somewhere else in another piece of code that wraps the call to DoSomething inside a using(Manager) block.

So my question is, what happens to the WCF call. Does it happen? Does it abandon?

And more generally, does this hold true for asynchronous calls using the `Task<T>` pattern? What happens if the owning class goes out of scope before the asynchronous call finishes?

Comment: using calls the dispose method of enclosing object. In that case client is probably disposed and calling task might cause exception.

Comment: @MuctadirDinar yes I agree that referencing the task object might indeed fail, but what happens to ReallyDoSomethingAsync? Does the call to the WCF service happen and go through to completion, regardless of the dead client?

Comment: If an object is dead how can you call one of its methods?

Comment: It's not dead at the point of calling it. Client.ReallyDoSomethingAsync(123) is a perfectly valid call at that stage. It returns a Task<bool>. AFTER that, it goes out of scope. So what happens to the Asynchronous call?

Comment: When `WcfClient` is disposed of (with `using`), I'd expect it to automatically cancel any async tasks it has created, including the one returned from `ReallyDoSomethingAsync`. So, outside the scope the task should be in cancelled state. I haven't verified that, though.

Comment: @Noseratio I guess the theories needs testing then, because we now have two opposing theories. Will investigate further...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After knocking-up a brief test app, it seems that when a WCF client is disposed, it waits for all async tasks to complete before it actually disposes.

Example WCF service:

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
 {
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        return "GOT HERE " + value;
    }
 }
```

Example client:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var wrapper = new Wrapper())
        {
            wrapper.DoSomething();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Wrapper : IDisposable
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Task<string> task1;

        using (var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
        {
            task1 = client.GetDataAsync(1);
            var task2 = client.GetDataAsync(2);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var task3 = client.GetDataAsync(3);

            Console.WriteLine("Calls started");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Result of task 1:" + task1.Result);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

In this scenario, the "Calls started" line appears after the 1 second delay. The "Finished." line does not get written until all the three tasks have completed successfully.

So it does in fact appear that the WCF Service Client wrapper manages its tasks and waits for completion (or presumably timeout) before disposing.

... Which gets me thinking: If you want to call a long running WCF method in a "fire and forget" asynchronous manner, you would either have to do it without a `using` block or wrap the whole thing in its own task. So that's a lot of wrapping!

Comment: Fascinating. Tomorrow I will delve deeper into this. Nice work!

Comment: Hmm, it should **not** really be waiting for task completion. @Simon, could you try it without `Thread.Sleep(1000)` and `Console.WriteLine` inside `using` and with changing `task1.Result` to `task1.Status` and let us know the value of `task1.Status`?

Comment: Done that. In DoSomething() if I now just start all 3 tasks, write their status and exit, it shows WaitingForActivation for all 3. And then waits for 5-6 seconds before leaving the using block.

Comment: if I modify it slightly and put a polling loop in DoSomething that polls the status every second for 10 seconds, all three tasks stay at the WaitingForActivation stage for 5-6 seconds and then jump to RanToCompletion. They never show the Running state.

Comment: What matters, the `Status` shows the tasks don't get cancelled. So now we know: apparently, the client proxy for a WCF service, when being disposed of, doesn't cancel its pending tasks. Interesting. This is in contrary to how I'd expect it to work. A good question, +1.

Comment: I agree I wasn't expecting to see that. I was expecting one of two things: 1. The disposal happens but doesn't affect the task (most likely) 2. The disposal cancels the task. 

However it turns out neither of those. Disposal waits for all tasks to end first!

Comment: BTW, just for the purpose of being complete, a breakpoint in the WCF service code shows that the code runs to completion on all three calls. And this happens BEFORE the dispose on the wrapper. So, in the absence of any other answer, I'm going to mark this one as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, each `Task` has two sides: the producer (which can be something like `TaskCompletionSource`) and the consumer (the `Task` itself).

Even when there are no references to the consumer side, there still is a reference to the producer side. What this means is that abandoning the `Task` won't do anything: the async call will continue as normal. And only after it completes, the `Task` will become eligible for garbage collection.

If you do want to cancel the asynchronous operation, you need to explicitly tell the producer to stop, which is usually done by passing it a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Thanks and Agreed. However, the behaviour I wasn't expecting to see what that the WCF Service Client appears to be waiting for asynchronous calls to complete/time out before disposing.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer for WCF specifically (that is, this doesn't address the question of "Does the service actually fire off the method call prior to leaving the `using` block).. but this:

```
Task<int> task;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\really_big_file.txt"))) {
    task = sr.ReadAsync(new char[2000000], 0, 2000000);
}

Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
```

Will fail with `Cannot access a closed file`. So, it would appear that there is no funny business going on here.. and everything runs as you would expect. `Dispose` is called, and attempting to access the resource tied to the task results in failure.

As for checking a WCF service call specifically.. I guess it's just another simple debug setup like this to test it.

In answer to your question about whether a task completes once it goes out of scope.. the answer is yes.

Tasks spawn threads. If you spawn a thread, you don't have to keep a reference to it. The ThreadPool will schedule it and it will run to completion.

See [the Thread documentation for a rundown on that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx).

Specifically, it says:

> It is not necessary to retain a reference to a Thread object once you have started the thread. The thread continues to execute until the thread procedure is complete.

Comment: Thanks. I agree in that situation, you get exactly what you'd expect because the very object the task is acting on goes out of scope. I appreciate you say that it is not a specific WCF question, but more generally, what happens when the task is acting on some other object and the reference to the task goes out of scope? Does the task itself complete?

Comment: Updated my answer to address that.

Comment: Ok, great so one would assume if the WCF client goes out of scope, along with the reference to the task, so long as the call started, it shouldn't matter - the call should carry on.

Comment: And thanks for taking the time to include a reference to the library page. Appreciated.

Comment: No worries. It's hard to say for sure that the WCF service would definitely call the method before going out of scope. When you take into consideration the threadpool firing up.. possibly building up a new thread, etc.. it's possible that `Dispose` is called before it can fire off the method call in a new thread.

Comment: Yeh, however you look at it - it's left wide open for problems relating to timing, etc. Which might explain why it's worked for months and now suddenly doesn't!

Comment: The obvious workaround is to spawn your own task that wraps the entire construct.. `using` and all..

Comment: I just wonder if the Async call blocks until the new thread has been given chance to fire up. Or is even the thread-creation process managed asynchronously?

Comment: Agreed - like I said before. It's bad code however you look at it. The possibility of going out of scope before threads given chance to start  is awful. Will refactor the whole thing!

Comment: See proposed answer, but it appears in fact that the WCF Client waits for tasks to complete before disposing.

Comment: “Tasks wrap threads.” That's really not true when it comes to async method.

Comment: @svick Can you suggest how I would rephrase that?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Maybe something like what I said in my answer? That there is always some “producer”, be it thread or async operation and that abandoning the `Task` does nothing to the producer.

Comment: Thanks @svick. I don't generally think of it as a "Producer-Consumer" scenario.. so I went with "spawn". However you have given me a different perspective to review this with :)